# Is there a timing function in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know if i could add timer to my code. Like do a command and then 3 seconds later another command. Like in my example, I have two boxes that i've created using css. But I want the first box to move immediately and the second a few seconds later, is it possible? If so, how?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#firstbox").animate({ top: '500px' }, 'slow');
    jQuery("#secondbox").animate({ top: '500px' }, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: @ArunPJohny [not enough jQuery...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) to set some delay before `animate()` run.

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

```
jQuery("#firstbox").animate({
    top: '500px'
}, 'slow');

jQuery("#secondbox").delay(3000).animate({
    top: '500px'
}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setTimeout` as follow:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#firstbox").animate({ top: '500px' }, 'slow');
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#secondbox").animate({ top: '500px' }, 'slow');
    },3000);
});
</script>
```