# Add a delay to existing code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an HTML file that when run, will open a URL in a new tab (the URL is pointing to a file on a local server, so when the HTML is run it in fact prompts the user to open or save the file), and then after x seconds, closes itself without the prompt asking the user if they wish to close the tab.

**Only** Internet Explorer can be used, as my company does not allow other browsers.

I already have a file that opens and closes the tab, however, the tab is closed almost immediately, which does not allow time for the prompt to come on-screen and ask the user if they wish to open or save the file. Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>You are being redirected</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content ="0; url=X:\\Directory\Subdirectory\File.docx">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('javascript:window.open("", "_self", "");window.close();', '_self');
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

A solution to my problem would be to just literally add a delay between the tab opening and closing in the above code (ideally 5 seconds or 5000 milliseconds). If anyone could show me how to add this delay before it closes that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Use [`settimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: I've asked this question before! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205643/is-there-a-timing-function-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    window.open('javascript:window.open("", "_self", "");window.close();', '_self');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: No problem Varx! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `settimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)
```

Read about it here: [**w3schools settimeout();**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This works to open a new tab and close it after 5 seconds

```
 var wnd = window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "");
    window.setTimeout(closeWindow, 5000);

    function closeWindow() {
        wnd.close();
    }
```